# Configure pagination with PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver for a RESTful server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, pagination

I'm writing a RESTful server with Spring Boot. I'm using Pageable to handle size and page parameters, and I want that a page number of 1 in the request will be considered the first page (the default is 0). Here's my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 20));
        resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }
}
```

Let's take an example with the following parameters: `?page=1&size=5`.

Without the line `resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);`, the server answers the page 2 with 5 elements (the page number starts at 0).

But when I don't, the server answers the first page (now the page number starts at 1) with **4** elements (obviously I want my server to answers with 5 elements instead of 4). And so on: with `size=6` I get 5 elements, etc.

My guess is `setOneIndexedParameters` impacts the size in addition to the page but it's a nonsense... And the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html#setOneIndexedParameters-boolean-) clearly mentions that it configures the page number only.

What did I miss? Thanks for help.

**EDIT :** Spring Boot version is 1.2.5.‌​RELEASE

Comment: Can you tell what spring data version are you on ? May be you are having hitting this bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-761

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.5.RELEASE`. I've upgraded to `1.4.1.RELEASE` and this issue is gone. I guess this post still deserves an answer for version `1.2.5.RELEASE`. Thanks for putting me in the way!

Comment: Ok, my version of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is using `spring-data-commons:1.9.3.RELEASE`, I've hit the bug you linked. Can you please add an answer so I can give you the bounty? Thanks.